# undefined method `has_attached_file error paperclip

Tags: ruby, paperclip

I am trying to use paperclip without rails(but trying to connect db created by rails).
Using bundler to require gems.

here are my models

```
class RailsDB < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection $db_config[:rails_db]
end
class VoiceCall < RailsDB
  belongs_to :campaign
  set_table_name :voice_calls

  has_attached_file :sound_file
  validates_attachment_presence :sound_file

end
```

If I try to run the program it throws the error

```
undefined method `has_attached_file
```

any idea y?
**Edit**:
my gem file

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'activerecord', '< 3.1', :require => 'active_record'
gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
```

I require gems using

```
require "bundler/setup"
Bundler.require(:default)
```

One more observation. I started irb and required active record and then paperclip. and ran this

```
p ActiveRecord::Base.methods.select{|m| m =~ /has_attached_file/}
```

It returns empty list.
but when I open rails console (using "rails c") the statement works and returns the value.( Both are using same gems)

Answer (score 0):

This error means the Paperclip gem is not loaded correctly (or at all) within your application.

Can you post your Gemfile and config/preinitializer.rb?

Is bundler working to successfully load other Gems in your environment?

I've seen this happen when Bundler was not configured correctly for a Rails project causing gems to fail to load.  The paperclip model references are the canary in the coal-mine for this larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue.

using

`gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"`

instead helped out.